# Unneeded backslashes when in json dumps method

Tags: python, json, string-literals

```
print(keystr)
print(addstr10)
dict[keystr] = addstr10
json.dump(dict, json_file, indent=2)
```

This yields for keystr = nested_object
and for addstr10 it yields

```
{"another_nested_object": {          "another_another_nested_object": "ymwjkxpr",          "integervalue" : 11,          "floatvalue" : 4.703165912962773,          "anothernamer" : True,          "another_nested_object_1": {                  "another_key": "vbiofdhz"          }       }     }
```

which look right but the json file has extra backslashes in the value pair and I want to get rid of it

```
{
  "nested_object": "{\"another_nested_object\": {          \"another_another_nested_object\": \"ymwjkxpr\",          \"integervalue\" : 11,          \"floatvalue\" : 4.703165912962773,          \"anothernamer\" : True,          \"another_nested_object_1\": {                  \"another_key\": \"vbiofdhz\"          }       }     }"
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. `json.dumps()` will always put quotes around strings.

Comment: Why is the value of `nested_object` a string rather than a dictionary?

Comment: I want "another_nested_object" to have quotes around it in the ouput like it does in the value pair.

Comment: It should do it. Please post some actual code, it's hard to tell what's going wrong from what you posted.

Comment: just updated my summary

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `addstr` is already encoded as JSON. So you're encoding it a second time when you include it as a value in the dictionary.

You should decode it first, so change

```
dict[keystr] = addstr10
```

to

```
dict[keystr] = json.loads(addstr10)
```

Howevever, the nested object contains invalid JSON. JSON uses `true` and `false` for booleans, but your string has `True`, which won't parse properly.

You could try using `ast.literal_eval()` instead of `json.loads()`.

```
import ast
dict[keystr] = ast.literal_eval(addstr10)
```

Comment: dict[keystr] = json.loads(addstr10)                                                                             
dict[keystr] = addstr10
json.dump(dict, json_file, indent=2)            Is this what you are referring to? If so it gives me a runtime error

Comment: x = json.loads(addstr8)
  File "C:\Users\williamzhang88\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\williamzhang88\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\williamzhang88\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)

Comment: The nested object is invalid JSON. `True` should be `true`.